# What rebinding a gridview has to do with edit mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, gridview

Gridview remains in EDIT mode when i don't rebind it, why ? but when i rebind gridview that it exits out of eidt mode successfully, why ?

code:

```
protected void gvTest_EditCancel(Object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e) 
{
    gvTest.EditIndex = -1;
  //  connectToDb();
    Response.Write("<br/>"+ "Editing cancelled");
}`

public void connectToDb() 
{
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(constrng);
    String com1 = "select * from login";
    SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(com1, sqlcon);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcom);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        sqlda.Fill(ds);
        gvTest.DataSource = ds;
        gvTest.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Response.Write(exc.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlcon.Close();
    }
}
```

but when call ConnectToDb() to rebind then it successfully exists out of edit mode,
what a rebinding has to do with EDITING or exiting of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the EditIndex that telling the gridview that it is in edit mode.

> The zero-based index of the row to edit. The default is -1, which
>   indicates that no row is being edited.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex.aspx).

When you edit the gridview, EditIndex is set to the GridView RowIndex, which is always 0 or greater than 0. so the GridView stays in edit mode. To exit edit mode, you need to set the index to -1. When you cancel edit, it sets this index to -1.

In RowCancelingEdit we can set the editindex to -1. But it will not change the row to normal mode until we rebind the row. When we rebind the gridview, it resets the row(OnRowDataBound). (But it doesn't reset the EditIndex, I was wrong about this). That's why whenever we do any row editing or deleting, we need to rebind the gridview,

So,

1. To exit edit mode, we have to set EditIndex = -1
2. EditIndex change will not reflect until we rebind the GridView.

Comment: ok but if REBINDING sets it to -1 mean no further editing then why setting gridview.editIndex= -1. it is not needed then because rebinding is doing the same job ? so what is this ? i'm getting confuse even more :(

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was wrong about resetting editindex on rebinding.

Comment: so the sequence is that when event triggers the method then it

1st: Sets the Editindex to -1 which mean that now it should exit from edit mode so it exists. 
2nd: Immediately a databind function is called so that refreshes the data in gridview so we can view a better interface and clean gridview.

IF: databind was not done than gridview from viewstate would have been picked and that would have presented a messy and unclear gridview

right or not ? correct me if it has to be. -afzalulh

Comment: Exactly. It is really hard to track the events as they are also related to page life cycle. Here's a link to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#databindingevents) that tell briefly about databinding events in Page Life Cycle.