# asp.net gridview control binding with other controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a asp.net webpage, it has 4 textboxes which stores value into a sql database,
i have created a gridview to this table, but it is showing values in the table before pageload
when i create a record using save button on this page the record is created on the background but it is not updated on the gridview.
How to bind the gridview with the buttons events on the page.

Comment: Can you please update the code that you have tried??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

call the grid binding function on save button. It would cause the grid re binding.

provide code for better answers.

these links may help:

[GridView not Rebinding Properly After Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759325/gridview-not-rebinding-properly-after-postback)

[What rebinding a gridview has to do with edit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326326/what-rebinding-a-gridview-has-to-do-with-edit-mode)

**Remember** Even the questions help.